# Connect timeout, database failover not working

Tags: c#, sql-server, failover, database-mirroring

I have implemented database mirroring on Azure with a witness, using SQL Server 2008. The mirroring / failover works on the SQL Server side. The problem I am having is that once a failover has occurred my asp.net Website does not connect to the new principle database and is still trying to connect the the old principle.

I have tried adding a 60s Connect Timeout to my connection string as suggested in this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/249589/db-auto-failover-in-c-does-not-work-when-the-principal-server-physically-goes-o). However this does not have any effect. And all I end up getting is the following error after around 60s:

> Request timed out.

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Any help much appreciated!

**EDIT**

My connection string is:

> data source=server1;Failover Partner=server2;initial catalog=DBNAME;User Id=WebsiteUser; Password=******;Connect Timeout=60;multipleactiveresultsets=True

Comment: Posting the connection string (sans credentials, if any) might be helpful...

Comment: @ta.speot.is have edited to reflect, thanks

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2010/12/08/clarification-on-the-failover-partner-in-the-connectionstring-in-database-mirror-setup.aspx has some documentation about this - e.g. pooled connections may not be aware of the failover.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: but shouldn't poooled connections thus only result in half the timeout delay to recognize the failover? EDIT: don'T mind, see scenario #5 for answer: "NO, IT WILL FAIL" :)

Comment: Thanks @ta.speot.is I am pretty sure it is pooled connections.

Answer (score 0):

did you add the failover partner to the connection string?
see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2010/12/08/clarification-on-the-failover-partner-in-the-connectionstring-in-database-mirror-setup.aspx for example and clarification

Comment: Yes I have added failover partner to my connection string.

Comment: I just checked: I set username, password, initial catalog, servernae, failover partner and timeout, thats all. BTW: my experience is when the principal fails, your first connection attempt will take about half the timeout and _afterwards_ connections will succeed to the failover partner (see msdn description of the underlying failover partner mechanics for reasons)